# Error abrir proyecto laravel windows

Tags: php, laravel, windows, apache, openssl

mi problema es que quiero hacer correr un proyecto laravel que ya tenia, y que hacia correr con XAMPP , luego por cuestiones solicitadas, desinstale xampp e instale manualmente Apache,PHP y Mysql, lo cual no me ha dado problemas hasta ahora, al hacer correr mi proyecto en el servidor, tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

busque, y encontre la solucion de utilizar:
composer install y/o composer update

y el problema es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de ello fui al archivo php.ini-development,
y agregue y descomente lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar lo siguiente.

- Verifica con phpinfo, si tienes instalado OpenSSL. Si no lo tienes tan solo debes descargarlo y luego incluir las dos DLL de OpenSSL que son `libeay32.dll` y `ssleay32.dll` en el directorio donde tienes PHP; Después reinicias el servidor.

Comment: instale open ssl en la carpeta C:\ , y descargue los dll y los ubique en c:\php , reinicie el servidor apache24, volvi a correr el proyecto, pero sigue igual.